Is there a way to get each value from a table then connect with it's title by row in a table

I have a table managed list of items (Green row), and its quantity by using a table (like a matrix). But in the end I want to combine it into one single string by each row, representing the quantity followed by the item name. For example I want to get a solution like the [TARGET ANSWER] column.
Is there any way to do it by formula ?
I have tried using CONCATENATE to connect the values and items, but it is too long. And later on if I added new items I have to change the formula again.
English is not my first language, sorry if it is hard to understand. You can check the image for better understanding.

The single formula
[J3]=ARRAYFORMULA((BYROW(IF(B3:I5="","",B3:I5&" "&B2:I2),LAMBDA(I,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,I))))



I have come up with a fairly verbose formula, but it should be able to handle column (item) additions dynamically.
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("A2:" & ADDRESS(2, COLUMN()-1))), INDIRECT("A2:" & ADDRESS(2, COLUMN()-1)) & " " & INDIRECT("A1:" & ADDRESS(1, COLUMN()-1)), "")))

The reason for using the ADDRESS() function here is to create a dynamic range from A2 up until the current cell. If the Target Answer is at column X2, this will go up to the column right before it, i.e. column W2.
The value returned by the ADDRESS() call is a cell reference represented as a string, such as W2. This is converted to an actual reference by INDIRECT() so that we can use the result in the call to TEXTJOIN() for concatenating the quantities.
Here's what the result looks like when I add an additional column (item) to the sheet:

In this way, you can move the Target Answer column ahead as you add items to your sheet and the formula does not need to be updated.

 TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(B2:B10 > 0, B2:B10 & " " & A2:A10, ""))

Place this formula in the desired cell.
Adjust the ranges (A2:A10 and B2:B10) as needed.
This will dynamically create a string with quantities followed by item names, updating automatically as you add items.
I hope understand trully, if it works let me know

Can you define the cell(s) to put this formula in? Did you check how it works?
